# Did Vladimir Lenin have a cat?

Tags: lenin

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Lenin#Personal_life_and_characteristics):

> He [Lenin] was... fond of pets, in particular cats.

So did Lenin, at some point, have a cat? I have seen some pictures of him holding cats, but I guess they could just be him holding someone else's cat (for popularity points).

Comment: The cat belonged to the people.

Comment: @ClintEastwood the cat was Lenin's ruler. As we all know, cats rule the world through their humans.

Comment: I know that he only drank coffee. Because all proper tea is theft.

Comment: @Richard Coffee is just tea made with ground coffee beans.

Comment: @corsiKa that's not 'proper tea'

Comment: No. Some cats may have had Vladimir Lenin, however.

Comment: He did, his cat's name was _Мисюсь_ (Misyusy, mee-SOOS), I even wrote a surrealistic metaphysical short film script about them, in Russian, called "Nitrous Kremlin". A translation into English is rather problematic, since, unlike Russian, in English "nitrogen" and "[Azoth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azoth)" sound completely different, but their total similarity in Russian is the main point of the plot. :)

Comment: @YellowSky So I've been discussing the plot of your film script with a friend and we're both interested: what is it about? It sounds like it's about lenin and his cat making nitrogen and Azoth? sounds weird, could you explain your project a little more, just out of curiosity. The main point of the plot is a pun?

Comment: @Féileacán - Here it is: https://www.facebook.com/notes/olexa-stomachenko/хф-кремлёвская-закись/1200951853264674/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It appears that Lenin did indeed own several cats over the years.

According to Louis Fischer's [The Life of Lenin](https://archive.org/details/lifeoflenin00fisc/page/366) (the source cited by the Wikipedia article):

> He had had a brown cat in Geneva.  During her visit to Lenin at Gorky shortly following the August 30, 1918, attempt on his life, Angelica Balabanoff saw two cats in the household. Lincoln Eyre, an American journalist who went to Lenin's Kremlin apartment, noted that the dictator was "fond" of his several cats.

- (p 367)

One reasonably well-known image that you may have seen is this one:

[image: Lenin with cat] (click to enlarge)

According to [this article](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/nov/06/lenins-disguise-little-seen-photos-of-soviet-leader-go-on-show) in the Guardian newspaper, the photograph was taken in 1922 by Lenin's sister "*at his residence in the village of Gorki*", and so could very well show one of the two cats seen by Angelica Balabanoff in 1918.

Comment: I think you mean that Lenin *was owned* by several cats? Your answer seems to have it backwards. My cats told me I may have to downvote you for that! ;)

Comment: @Marakai Non-adopted humans have a hard time understanding the difference. They have to be domesticated by a cat first.

Comment: @Marakai Ah, but as the saying goes, in Soviet Russia...

Comment: The cat was his [familiar](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/familiar)

Answer (score 11):

Victor Sebestyen's book '[Lenin the Dictator](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FH-LCwAAQBAJ)' says that after the Bolsheviks had seized power and Lenin and his wife Nadezhda Krupskaya were living in a flat in the Kremlin, Lenin, despite his many other responsibilities as a ruthless Communist Dictator, always remembered to feed their cat, which his wife would often forget.

Sebestyen does not say what the cat was called or what colour it was.